# Fat Free router blocks Backbone router, how/when does Backbone router.js work?

Tags: backbone.js, routes, fat-free-framework

I have a Backbonejs (BB) project setup. I have Fat Free Framework (F3) running for the server-side code. As I ask this, please keep in mind I'm just learning these two web dev tools: When does the BB router do any routing? I have a link in a web page that matches a route in the BB router, but the F3 router keeps trying to handle it and failing. How do these two routers work together and not interfere?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: To me, it doesn't really make a sense to have routes in both frameworks. Either you develop most of the stuff in Backbone.js and use F3 just for the DB stuff, or vise versa and Backnbone.js ist just responsible for events and view.

Comment: @Sn0opy: Yes, this is _exactly_ what I'm attempting to do. Develop the app in near entirety with BB, only use F3 for the server-side database communication bit. Trying to figure this out.

Comment: @muistooshort: I'll post the BB code when I get back home this eve.

Comment: Perhaps my answer is to move the index.php (with F3 routes) from the web site root into the 'server' subfolder. Then in BB I would call them like /server/members or /server/comments and so on.

Comment: Wow is this unbelievably frustrating. Nothing works. It doesn't matter in what directory I put the .htaccess file and/or the index.php with F3 routing, it doesn't matter what the RewriteBase is or the RewriteRule, all you get is 404 errors over and over and over and over. Here is what I conclude after about a week of failing to get BB and F3 to work: _BB and F3 were **never** intended to be used together, not ever._ If they were, you could google and find an article _somewhere_ that explains how to make them work together and you cannot find this article. Now I have to figure out plan B :-/

Comment: Aaaand... when I'm 60 seconds from completely giving up, I try one last idea and now it works. Incredible :-/

Yes I will put all of this in a blog when I get it working.

Comment: Ok the F3 part is working. BB router still does nothing. It never has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using pushState, then the backbones routes are easy to differentiate from the server routes:

- /route1
- /route2
- /route1#route/a
- /route1#route/b

The part before the hash is the one transmitted to the server (F3 routes). The part after the hash corresponds to the backbone routes.

```
//F3 routing
$f3->route('GET /route1',…)
$f3->route('GET /route2',…)

//Backbone routing
routes: {
  "route/a": "routeA",
  "route/b": "routeB",
}
```

Note that the Backbone router doesn't generate any HTTP request to the server (unless you specifically define it of course).

What generates automatically HTTP requests is the Backbone model. A backbone model is mapped to a server resource using `urlRoot`. The methods `fetch()`, `save()` and `destroy()` are then mapped respectively to the GET, PUT and DELETE HTTP methods.

Check this example:

```
userModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot: '/user'
});
var user=new userModel({id:123});
user.fetch();// GET /user/123
user.save();// PUT /user/123
user.destroy();// DELETE /user/123
```

On the server side, you can easily map a User class like this:

```
$f3->map('/user/@id','User');
class User {
  function get($f3,$args){…}
  function put($f3,$args){…}
  function delete($f3,$args){…}
}
```

Comment: It's the hashtag in the url that I was missing. It's not mentioned in the BB router instructions and it's critical :-/ I believe now I have almost all of the parts working. @xfra35: Thanks a ton for your help :-) I was getting a bit fried.

Comment: You're welcome :) Here's a [short tutorial](http://backbonetutorials.com/) I found to be very instructive to start with Backbone.

Comment: Ah geez, I've seen that article. I've read a good bit of it before. But for some reason the clearly stated info in the router section about that hashtag just didn't stick. I feel a little dumb :-/

The F3 routing part and .htaccess file setup wasn't too simple either.